# foreign key field is null in a one to many relationship (symfony2)

Tags: forms, symfony, one-to-many

I have two tables with an `one to many` relationship. My code works fine and the form uses interactive mode for adding details, but when I submit it, everything except the `foreign key id`, which is `null`, is saved. Therefore the data on the secondary table is not in a relationship with the primary table. Where is the problem?

Here is my primary table (only some attr):

```
    <?php

namespace Alg\NormasBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Requisitos
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\RequisitosRepository")
 */
class Requisitos
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idrequisito", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RequisitosDetalle", mappedBy="requisito", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $detalle;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->detalle = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Add detalle
     *
     * @param \Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\RequisitosDetalle $detalle
     * @return Requisitos
     */
    public function addDetalle(\Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\RequisitosDetalle $detalle)
    {
        $this->detalle[] = $detalle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove detalle
     *
     * @param \Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\RequisitosDetalle $detalle
     */
    public function removeDetalle(\Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\RequisitosDetalle $detalle)
    {
        $this->detalle->removeElement($detalle);
    }

    /**
     * Get detalle
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDetalle()
    {
        return $this->detalle;
    }
}
```

Here is my secondary table:

```
    <?php

namespace Alg\NormasBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RequisitosDetalle
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\RequisitosDetalleRepository")
 */
class RequisitosDetalle
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="iddetalle", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Requisitos", inversedBy="detalle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idrequisito", referencedColumnName="idrequisito")
     */
    private $requisito;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tema", type="text")
     */
    private $tema;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="disposicion", type="text")
     */
    private $disposicion;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="articulos", type="text")
     */
    private $articulos;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="aplicacion", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $aplicacion;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="evidencia", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $evidencia;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cargos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idcargo", referencedColumnName="idcargo")
     */
    private $cargo;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set tema
     *
     * @param string $tema
     * @return Requisitos
     */
    public function setTema($tema)
    {
        $this->tema = $tema;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tema
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTema()
    {
        return $this->tema;
    }

    /**
     * Set disposicion
     *
     * @param string $disposicion
     * @return Requisitos
     */
    public function setDisposicion($disposicion)
    {
        $this->disposicion = $disposicion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get disposicion
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDisposicion()
    {
        return $this->disposicion;
    }

    /**
     * Set articulos
     *
     * @param string $articulos
     * @return Requisitos
     */
    public function setArticulos($articulos)
    {
        $this->articulos = $articulos;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get articulos
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getArticulos()
    {
        return $this->articulos;
    }

    /**
     * Set aplicacion
     *
     * @param string $aplicacion
     * @return Requisitos
     */
    public function setAplicacion($aplicacion)
    {
        $this->aplicacion = $aplicacion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get aplicacion
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAplicacion()
    {
        return $this->aplicacion;
    }

    /**
     * Set evidencia
     *
     * @param string $evidencia
     * @return Requisitos
     */
    public function setEvidencia($evidencia)
    {
        $this->evidencia = $evidencia;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get evidencia
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEvidencia()
    {
        return $this->evidencia;
    }

    public function addRequisito(\Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\Requisitos $requisito)
    {
        if (!$this->requisito->contains($requisito)) {
            $this->requisito->add($requisito);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set requisito
     *
     * @param \Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\Requisitos $requisito
     * @return Requisitos
     */
    public function setRequisito(\Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\Requisitos $requisito = null)
    {
        $this->requisito = $requisito;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get requisito
     *
     * @return \Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\Requisitos 
     */
    public function getRequisito()
    {
        return $this->requisito;
    }



    /**
     * Set cargo
     *
     * @param \Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\Cargos $cargo
     * @return Requisitos
     */
    public function setCargo(\Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\Cargos $cargo = null)
    {
        $this->cargo = $cargo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cargo
     *
     * @return \Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\Cargos 
     */
    public function getCargo()
    {
        return $this->cargo;
    }
}
```

form type of the secondary table:

```
    <?php

namespace Alg\NormasBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
//use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class abmRequisitoDetalleType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('tema', null, array('label' => 'Tema:'))
                ->add('disposicion', null, array('label' => 'Disposición:'))
                ->add('articulos', null, array('label' => 'Artículos:'));
                //->add('aplicacion', null, array('label' => 'Aplicación:'))
                //->add('evidencia', null, array('label' => 'Evidencia:'));
        //  ->add('cargo', 'entity', array('label' => 'Disposición:'));

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\RequisitosDetalle'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fdetalle';
    }
}
```

form type of the primary table:

```
    <?php

namespace Alg\NormasBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Alg\NormasBundle\Form\Type\abmRequisitoDetalleType;

class abmRequisitoType extends AbstractType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fecha', null, array('label' => 'Fecha Redacción:',
                                                'widget' => 'single_text'))
                ->add('titulo', null, array('label' => 'Título Documento:'));

        $builder->add('detalle', 'collection', array(
                                'type'           => new abmRequisitoDetalleType(),
                                'label'          => 'Detalle de Requisitos Legales:',
                                'by_reference'   => false,
                                'allow_delete'   => true,
                                'allow_add'      => true,
                                'attr'           => array('class' => 'elDetalle')
                    )   );

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\Requisitos',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'frequisito';
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
public function newAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //nuevo
        $requisito = new Requisitos();
        $requisito->setFecha(new \DateTime('now'));
    $form = $this->createForm(new abmRequisitoType(), $requisito);
    //-- En caso de que el request haya sido invocado por POST procesaremos el formulario
    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        //-- Pasamos el request al método bindRequest() del objeto formulario el cual obtiene los datos del formulario
        // y los carga dentro del objeto fhallazgo1 que está contenido también dentro del objeto Type
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        //-- Con esto nuestro formulario ya es capaz de decirnos si los datos son válidos o no 
        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $requisito->setEstado('1');
            $repository->persist($requisito);
            $repository->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateURL('alg_normas_requisitoelab'));
        }
    }
    // Ingresamos al formulario
    return $this->render('AlgNormasBundle:Requisitos:new.html.twig', 
                            array('form' => $form->createView(), 
                                'requisito' => $requisito ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function addDetalle(\Alg\NormasBundle\Entity\RequisitosDetalle $detalle)
{
    $this->detalle[] = $detalle;

    $detalle->setRequisitos($this); // *** Add this

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist()
* @ORM\PreUpdate()
*/

public function processPre()
{
    foreach ($this->detalle as $key => $obj) {
        if ($obj->getRequisitos() === null) {
            $obj->setRequisitos($this);
            $this->detalle[$key] = $obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)